# How to dismiss local notification in flutter without bring app in foreground

Tags: flutter, android-notifications, flutter-local-notification

I am using [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications/versions/0.0.6+9) and want to **dismiss** as well as **not bring the app in foreground** when the 'Mark as read' is clicked in the notification.

App correctly **not bring the app in foreground** , but the notification does not get dismissed.

Below is the code

```
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null,
      [
        NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'basic_channel',
            channelName: 'Basic notifications',
            channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
            // defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
            // ledColor: Colors.white
      )
      ],
      debug: false);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });

    AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
            id: 10,
            channelKey: 'basic_channel',
            title: 'Simple Notification',
            body: 'Simple body',
            payload: {'uuid': 'user-profile-uuid'}),
        actionButtons: [
          NotificationActionButton(
              key: 'READ',
              label: 'Mark as read',
              autoCancel: true,
              buttonType: ActionButtonType.DisabledAction),
          NotificationActionButton(
              key: 'PROFILE',
              label: 'Show Profile',
              autoCancel: false,
              enabled: true,
              buttonType: ActionButtonType.Default)
        ]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
      if (!isAllowed) {
        AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
      }
    });

    AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
      debugPrint(
          "  actionStream received " + receivedNotification.toString());
    });

    AwesomeNotifications().createdStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
      debugPrint(
          "  createdStream received " + receivedNotification.toString());
    });

    AwesomeNotifications().displayedStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
      debugPrint(
          "  displayedStream received " + receivedNotification.toString());
    });

    AwesomeNotifications().dismissedStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
      debugPrint(
          "  dismissedStream received " + receivedNotification.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        //
        child: Column(
          //
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can the notification can also be dismissed ? Before and after [image: screenshot]

As buttonType for 'Mark as read' is ActionButtonType.DisabledAction it correctly does not bring the application in the foreground( one of the requirement), but the second requirement of 'dismissing' ( ie. notification being cleared, is not occurring and notification is staying. How the notification be cleared at same time ?

Comment: why click on dismiss rather just swapping the notification?

Comment: @RusJ swapping is to ignore the notification, when an action( such as **MARK AS READ**) is clicked, it is supposed to do an operation as well as take away the notification.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, your code is right. **ActionButtonType.DisabledAction** should remove the notification from the tray. But it don't (Even in the example app). I think it's a bug. You can create a GitHub issue and request a fix. One more thing, **AwesomeNotifications().dismiss(id)** removes the notification. But Awesome Notification doesn't support custom action. So, I think you have to wait for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code can help you

```
int id=Random().nextInt(1000);
await NotificationHandler.flutterLocalNotificationPlugin.show(
    id, title, body, platform,
    payload: 'my payload');
await NotificationHandler.flutterLocalNotificationPlugin.cancel(id);
```

or Follow this link can help
[About Handle Notification](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#foreground-notifications)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).